# QR code scanner using android studio

Tags: android, zxing

I am looking for a tutorial that shows how to make a Qr code scanner using Zxing and android studio, there are many on there internet but all of theme use eclipse, when i try to follow the same steps in android studio it doesn't work.

Comment: link to your tutorial please

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for you responses , i find that there is an easy way to do that using build.gradle
here is the link : 
http://www.lihongfei.com/integrate-zxing-in-android-studio/

there is a little bug to fix because the scan works for the first time , but not for the second.
just use this function to initiate the scan

```
public void performScan(){
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) lib.

If wraps 2 popular libraries for QR code scanning for Android: **ZXing** and **ZBar**. Which to use - is up to you!